# Is it possible to pass a parameter to a nestjs guard?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to come up with a somewhat reusable guard and it looks like I need to pass a string param to a guard. Is it achievable in nestjs?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to use a `mixin`, a function that returns a class. I'm not sure what kind of parameter you're passing, but the idea is

```js
export const RoleGuard = (role: string) => {
  class RoleGuardMixin implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
      // do something with context and role
      return true;
    }
  }

  const guard = mixin(RoleGuardMixin);
  return guard;
}
```

`mixin` as a function is imported from `@nestjs/common` and is a wrapper function that applies the `@Injectable()` decorator to the class

Now to use the guard, you need to do something like `@UseGuards(RoleGuard('admin'))`

Comment: @SimonSchürg seeing what code you have would be necessary to determine the problem. I've used this pattern several times without fail.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have figured out the exception problem in my nest js code. To my suprise it had not to do with the mixin guard pattern. The reason was that I used a guard in one controller wrong. So sorry for the not related comment. I deleted it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel but if without mixin or with @UseGuards(new PermissionsGuard2('test'))

Comment: @Michael if you have a new question, it may be best to create a new post. From your comment, I can't tell what's being asked here

Comment: Just a heads up for people running into TS errors with this solution, it can be easily resolved by changing the return type of `RoleGuard` (ie. `export const RoleGuard = (role: string): Type<CanActivate> ...`. Otherwise the return type is a private class, which will fail.

Comment: Error : Exported variable 'RoleGuard' has or is using private name 'RoleGuardMixin'

Comment: I get a runtime error: metatype is not a constructor

Comment: @TruMan1 what are you passing to `@UseGuards()`?

Comment: "metatype is not a constructor" means you are not calling the mixin function itself. `@UseGuards(UploadGuard)` -> `@UseGuards(UploadGuard(params))`

Comment: You saved my day :-)

Answer (score 18):

It seems impossible to use mixin in Guard in NestJs. It will throw Exported variable 'RoleGuard' has or is using private name 'RoleGuardMixin'.

Actually, you may use setMetadata to pass in the parameters one by one, then get it from the Guard using reflector from from '@nestjs/core'.

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {
        constructor(
            private reflector: Reflector,
        ) {}

        canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
          const roleName = this.reflector.get<string>('roleName', context.getHandler());
          return true;
        }
    }
```

```js
    @Get()
    @SetMetadata('roleName', 'developer')
    async testRoleGuard() {
      return true;
    }
```

Or you may define a decorator to pass the parameter in.

```js
export const RoleName = (roleName: string) => SetMetadata('roleName', roleName);
```

```js
    @Get()
    @RoleName('developer')
    async testRoleGuard() {
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is struggling with testing the mixin approach @JayMcDoniel brilliantly pointed out, here's a sample setup from a guard I implemented using the mixin.

```js
describe('PaymentGuard', () => {
  let guard: CanActivate;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const guardProvider = PaymentGuard(PaymentGuardHandlerToken.EXPECT_PLATFORM_ENABLED);
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        guardProvider,
        {
          provide: PaymentService,
          useValue: MOCK_PAYMENT_SERVICE,
        },
        {
          provide: EntityManager,
          useValue: MOCK_ENTITY_MANAGER,
        }
      ],
    }).compile();
    guard = module.get(guardProvider);
  });
});
```

And then you just call the `guard.canActivate` within your test.

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:**

```js
@UseGuards(new AuthorizeGuard('read', 'users'))
```

**Guard:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizeGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private action, private subject) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    //you can use this.action and this.subject
  }
}
```

Comment: If iam use this, how do i inject some service ?

Comment: Bad approach, creates new guard instances for every controller